# ResNet50 keras giving wrong shaped output when top = False

Tags: python, deep-learning, size, resnet, transfer-learning

For transfer learning I am using ResNet50 as a feature extractor. By making top = False I am taking the output from the layer which is just before the last layer. The output should have a size of `(#examples, 7, 7, 2048)` as documentation of ResNet50. But I faced an strange issue. I am getting the output shape of `(#examples, 8, 8, 2048)`. Following is the code:

```
model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False)
# batchImages is a list containing images in that batch
# bs is the batch size
features = model.predict(batchImages, batch_size = bs)
```

Here the shape of the feature should be `(#examples, 7, 7, 2048)` but it is giving `(#examples, 8, 8, 2048)`. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely normal, the size reduction in ResNet is given by the MaxPooling of size 2x2 after each block. Since there are 5 blocks in Resnet, you will always get input_size / 2**5.
224 / 32 = 7
256 / 32 = 8

Answer (score 0):

As I have found the output feature size in ResNet50 (with top = False) depends on the input shape of the images. Although in documentations I found that the output feature shape in this cases would be `(#examples, 7, 7, 2048)` but it changes when I change the input image shape. Although I didn't find any clarification on this anywhere. But as I have seen whenever I am using images of size `(224 x 224)` it is working completely okay. But when I increase the input image's size to `(255 x 255)` the output feature vector size changes to `(#examples, 8, 8, 2048)`. This looks weird but actually this is happening.